# Is there a way to make vi and vim behave differently on OSX?

Tags: vim, vi

Is there a way to have two separate config files or somehow disassociate vi and vim on Mac OSX?  Simply, I want vi and vim to open up in 2 different window sizes.  Thanks!

Comment: Who uses plain old vi anymore?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `v:progname` variable:

```
if v:progname == 'vi'
    " vi-compatible settings
else
    " full vim settings
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as using `.virc` and `.vimrc` as appropriate.

Comment: I thought so too, but that doesn't seem to work.  Doesn't seem to use that config file.

Comment: alias vi to be vi -c ~/.virc or whatever it is to source the right file.  On OSX, I suspect that 'vi' is simply a symlink to vim.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: Indeed!

`$ vi --version` -->
`VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Jan 31 2010 13:33:49)`